# Center the different blocks in a v-card

Tags: vue.js, element, vuetify.js

I would like to center the login, password and login blocks.
I want to center the different blocks but I do not know how to do it at this level.
I tried with v-flex and v-layout but it does not pass.
In the code I tried to center the first and second block with v-layout and v-flex but without satisfactory result.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar
      color="teal accent-3"
      dark
    >

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-flex xs="12"><p class="text-justify">Application de traitement des opérations</p></v-flex>
      <v-menu
        left
        bottom
      >
      
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="n in 5"
            :key="n"
            @click="() => {}"
          >
            <v-list-item-title>Option {{ n }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </v-app-bar>
   <div>
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      height="100"
      max-width="200"
      outlined
      color="orange lighten-2"
    ></v-card>
    <v-card
      class="mt-n12 mx-auto"
      elevation="12"
      height="400"
      max-width="600"
    >
    <V-layout>
    <v-flex xs="12">
      <div class="text-xs-center">
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
          <v-text-field
            label="Solo"
            placeholder="Login"
            solo
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
          <v-text-field
            label="Solo"
            placeholder="Mot de passe"
            solo
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </div>

        <el-button type="primary" @click="dialogVisible = true" >Connexion</el-button>

        <el-dialog
          title="Verification de Connexion"
          :visible.sync="dialogVisible"
          width="30%"
          :before-close="handleClose">
          <span>Connexion reussi</span>
          <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
            <el-button @click="dialogVisible = false">Annuler la connexion</el-button>
            <el-button type="primary" @click="dialogVisible = false">Continuer</el-button>
          </span>
        </el-dialog>
      </v-flex >

    </V-layout>
    </v-card>
  </div>
  
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do this. You could use flex with display row, but it sounded like you tried that? If so you can also try setting these to display: block, and setting margin: auto.